# making a div the same size as an img pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ue7pq/

and the equivalent jQuery fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ldn9P/

html:

```
<div class="project-box">
  <img src="img/ifix.jpg" class="thumbnail img-responsive">
  <div class="hover-box">
    <h2>TITLE</h2>
    <p>Description of logos that we've made</p>
  </div>
 </div>
```

js:

```
window.onload = function(){

var project = document.getElementsByClassName('project-box');
img = project[0].getElementsByTagName('img');
box = document.querySelectorAll('div.project-box div.hover-box');
imgWidth = img[0].offsetWidth;
imgHeight = img[0].offsetHeight;
console.log(imgWidth);
console.log(imgHeight);

box.style.width = imgWidth+'px';
box.style.height = imgHeight+'px';

};
```

I'm trying to make the hover-box the same width and height as the img. I'm trying to keep this as pure javascript I made the mistake of learning jQuery first and not JavaScript so now I'm trying to teach myself JavaScript having some issues. The console log says that hoverbox is undefined

error message in console.log:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: hoverBox is not defined main.js: 4
350 
180 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'width' of undefined
```

Comment: after you learn javascript you going to love jquery...lol

Comment: @EmilioGort I already love jQuery lol but I feel like I need to know the roots to advance my skills in jQuery

Comment: do you have a [fiddley](http://jsfiddle.net/) to try?

Comment: I agree completely, swsa -- good choice. jQuery is a great shortcut, but I think it is critical to your skills to know what you're cutting. Otherwise, a shortcut can turn in to a longcut.

Comment: @EmilioGort whats findley?

Comment: I never learnt to manipulate the DOM using pure JavaScript to this level and never needed to. If you're going to end up using jQuery or another library you probably don't need to. Learning JavaScript as a language (separate from DOM manipulation) is probably going to be more useful I think. I found http://javascript.didacto.net interesting.

Comment: Could you plz paste the exact error message you see in the console?

Comment: why not using project[0].getElementsByClassName('hover-box');

Comment: This is not making sense since you are not referring any variable named hoverBox in the code that you have posted. Did you copy the code in the question from your JS file or type it in? I suspect that the two versions are different.

Comment: @Chandranshu thats what I dont understand either I copied pasted it i made a jsfiddle that gives me the same errors

Comment: Agreed -- your code does not match your error.

Comment: Pro-tip: USE INDENTATION! :P Seriously, though, choose an indentation style and become militant about it. A fanatic. Start thinking less of other developers that don't use your chosen style of indentation. Arrange your food on your plate in the proper hierarchy. Obsess about it.

Comment: While @Chris has already answered your question, I just checked your fiddle and saw that your error message doesn't contain the ReferenceError. You should clear your console each time after you make changes to the code. Also, when you edit your posts, **include your edits at the bottom** unlike the jsfiddle link at the top.

Comment: You don't want to do this with CSS?

Comment: @AramKocharyan I don't think learning the plain language of javascript by starting with DOM manipulation is mutually exclusive with learning the rest of the core fundamentals in the language. It is a good start, and hopefully builds confidence to bud out. Often, working with DOM in javascript creates scenarios where you need to develop tools that lead you into the more advance concepts. At any rate, you can't go wrong learning new things. Also... do this with CSS for a real website, +1 thgaskell

Comment: @thgaskell  the thing is im trying to make it so its always the size of the img even if the window is resized so css wouldnt allow me to do that here is a jsfiddle of how it works with jquery
http://jsfiddle.net/Ldn9P/

Comment: @Chris the thing is im trying to make it so its always the size of the img even if the window is resized so css wouldnt allow me to do that here is a jsfiddle of how it works with jquery  http://jsfiddle.net/Ldn9P/

Comment: With different markup and css transitions, you could come pretty close :)

Comment: @swsa for example: http://jsfiddle.net/j4n9H/

Comment: @thgaskell thats dope thanks man

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`querySelectorAll` returns a list of elements, but you're treating it as if it references a single element.

I suggest grabbing a list of the project boxes, then looping them and resizing each. That way, if there are more than one on the page then they will all be affected. This would be like doing this in jQuery: `$('.project-box').each(function () { ... });`

```
var project_boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('project-box');
for (var i = 0, len = project_boxes.length; i < len; i++) {
    var img = project_boxes[i].querySelectorAll('img.thumbnail');
    var box = project_boxes[i].querySelectorAll('div.hover-box');

    if (box.length > 0 && img.length > 0) {
        box[0].style.width = img[0].offsetWidth+'px';
        box[0].style.height = img[0].offsetHeight+'px';
    }
}
```

Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/EsJ4k/ (note: images not present, so code results in 0px height and width)

**Documentation**

- `querySelectorAll` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll
- `getElementsByClassName` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName

Comment: for some reason it works fine but still gives me the error Uncaught ReferenceError: hoverBox is not defined

Comment: by the way what are some good books you recommend for me to learn JavaScript I recently bought JavaScript the definitive guide edition 6 waiting for it in the mail but I would obviously like to read a lot more than one book any recommendations?

Comment: http://javascript.crockford.com/ and his book is a good companion to the book you've got coming. Also, simply going to codepen or github and tinkering with existing code can often be instructive.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
    <div class="project-box">
  <img src="http://www.samdeveloper.com/images/sam_devloperr.jpg" class="thumbnail img-responsive">
      <div class="hover-box">
        <h2>TITLE</h2>
        <p>Description of logos that we've made</p>
      </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.project-box{position:relative; width:100%;}
.project-box .hover-box{position:absolute; bottom:0; width:100%; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.5); display:none;}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){   
    $(".thumbnail").css("width","100%");
    $(".project-box").hover(function(){
        $(".hover-box").fadeIn(1000);
    },function(){
        $(".hover-box").fadeOut(1000);
    });
});
```

Online demo for [Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/x8f6h/5/)

Comment: OP did specify no jQuery. Also, if going for a CSS solution, you could use css transitions and `opacity` to eliminate the need for the script all together.

Answer (score -1):

```
window.onload = function(){
var project = document.getElementsByClassName('project-box');
img = project[0].getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
box = document.querySelectorAll('div.project-box, div.hover-box');
imgWidth = img.offsetWidth;
imgHeight = img.offsetHeight;
for(var i = 0; i < box.length;i++){
    box[i].style.width = imgWidth+"px";
    box[i].style.height = imgHeight+"px";
}
};
```